# Android Studio, Is there a refresh button. Every time I make changes in xml I need to close and reopen studio to see changes on the design

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Every time I try to hardcode designs in the xml; the changes are not present in the design; like I need to close and reopen Android Studio for me to see changes that I have made. Same with adding images to the drawable resource folder; I need to close and reopen Android Studio, so that Android Studio can even recognize that there is a file in the drawable folder.

It is like Android Studio is not up date to changes made and thus needs to be closed and opened again. Is there a refresh button or something for this; or what could possibly fix this?

Comment: which version of android studio ur using ?

Comment: I have version 3.0.1

Answer (score 4):

You can try Rebuild the Project (In build menu)

OR

There is a Refresh option in design view. Click on Force Refresh Layout (This may vary as per Android Studio versions)

[image]

Comment: What would the refresh button look like? Also I have tried rebuild project and that has not worked.

Comment: Ok I have included a picture.

Comment: @FranticCelery if this answer worked for you could you mark it as accepted? [accepting answers is an important part](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/165773) of how SO works

Answer (score 1):

Just click Preview Button twice it will refresh the current layout. However, Android Studio automatically update all drawable files and the current xml design in preview.

Try rebuild/clean your project also Invalidate/Caches restart once.

Comment: Solved it; If I go to the design tab and press R; the screen refreshes itself. Thanks everyone for the help!