# Drawer preview not showing properly in menu file

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, androidx

I'm building an app in android studio with a menu (lateral drawer), and i want to see the preview in the menu.xml file, but it shows a grey screen, it shows fine in the emulator but not in android studio

It works fine without `tools:showIn="navigation_view"` but i want to see the preview with navigation_view like the image below

[This is what the preview looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8OaC.png)

[It should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjiCF.png)

I have tried rebuilding the app, which is the most common solution, but it still doesn't show up

This is the xml file of the menu

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_inicio"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_message"
            android:title="Inicio" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_animales"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_chat"
            android:title="Animales" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_agregar"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile"
            android:title="Agregar" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_editar"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile"
            android:title="Editar" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_borrar"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile"
            android:title="Borrar" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_share"
                android:title="Share" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_send"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_send"
                android:title="Share" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

dependencies

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "expo.desarrollo.simbad_app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `invalidate Caches/ Restart` by going to `File` in the Android Studio. If still no showing then, try `force refresh layout` from the XML design screen, can't find it? follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48096839/android-studio-is-there-a-refresh-button-every-time-i-make-changes-in-xml-i-ne):

Answer (score 0):

Please Add Design Library in Gradle Build (App Module)
after that hope it will work.

implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

Comment: The app uses androidx and that library is the same as `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'` in androidx, adding `com.android.support:design:28.0.0` gives an error